# Connecting Dreamweaver to MySQL on localhost

Tags: mysql, dreamweaver

We are running our site locally under Xampp. We can access MySql via PHPMyAdmin fine but are unable to conect to our database via DreamWeaver.
When we enter the details to create a connection we get the following error

"An unidentified error has occured"

We have checked the connection details in the configuration.php file

```
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'richard';
public $password = 'xxxxxxxxx';
public $db = 'theplan8_planes';
```

but when we use them we get the error.

Thanks
Richard

Comment: Have you tried `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost?

Comment: Are you connecting on the right port?

Comment: Hi
Xampp runs on port 85 but have tried all combinations
localhost:85, 127.0.0.1:85 etc 
The details entered are as per the configuration.php file but get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the MySqlServer entry we had to add the port number 3306 to localhost
Localhost:3306

Rich